# "va_start used in function with fixed args" exception?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to create a simple macro using varargs, but I'm getting "va_start used in function with fixed args" and I don't understand why and where I'm wrong. The code is the following:

```
#define FOO(obj, ...) \
    va_list args; \
    va_start(args, obj); \
    NSString *currentObject; \
    while ((currentObject = va_arg(args, NSString*)) != nil) { \
        NSLog(@"string: %@", currentObject); \
    } \
    va_end(args);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `va_list` type and its associated operations are for variadic *functions*. They don't work for variadic macros, which use `__VA_ARGS__` and work somewhat differently.

In this example I can't see any reason to use a macro; you should probably just use a function instead. If it turns out that you do need a macro, you will probably end up having to pass `__VA_ARGS__` as the arguments to a variadic function, which can then unpack the arguments and perform further work.

Answer (score 1):

Macros aren't functions. In fact, they don't even work anything *like* functions. In particular, they don't really "do" variable arguments.

To wit: When you insert this in some other function or method, the macro is expanded and inserted *textually*. Unless that function has a variable argument list starting after whatever you passed in as `obj`, that just won't do.

(There are ways to get macros to "do" variable arguments, but it's almost certainly a terrible idea, and almost certainly not necessary.)